# Returning the gridview to its original vertical location after the rowediting postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Using a combination of asp.net, jQuery, and c# and stored procedures.

I have successfully created a gridview, which I then apply jQuery datatables plugin to provide text column filtering (I disabled most of the other datatables function/settings off)).

The Gridview works as expected and when I make use of the `RowEditing` and `RowUpdating` events also, IE the editable fields update nicely.

If the user clicks and edits, then clicks the update link, the database is updated and the page reloads. now if that person has scrolled down say record 50 (half way down for instance) in order to locate and then edit that record, then after the page refresh, the user then has to scroll back down to find that same record.

I'm trying to find a way of returning the user to the same location (record) that they had just edited before the page refresh after the page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood; your dilemma is nothing to do with gridviews etc, and is all to do with merely maintaining page scroll position on post-back... [have a read of this JavaScript solution from the 4 guys](https://web.archive.org/web/20211027114245/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111704-1.aspx)

P.S. Google is your friend

Comment: I could not get that to work and then stumbled over a page directive: MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="True" and this worked

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution to my problem with out a load of coding and it turned out to be MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="True" page directive.

Comment: Have you tried this in different browsers? Usually it works in IE but not in other browsers such as Chrome / Safari / FireFox for example.